# get azure resources used by azure-dataexplorer cluster using azure sdk

Tags: azure-data-explorer

in azure portal, i created an azure kusto cluster with a virtual net and public ip.

Is any way to retrieve all the azure resources (virtual net, public ip, loadbalancer etc) associated with my kusto cluster programatically using the azure sdks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you manage all those resources under the same resource group.

Then, you can use list resources by resource group API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/listbyresourcegroup